# T-SQL Error trying to join table function in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have a table valued function I need to use in a stored procedure:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES(getdate()) e (NOLOCK) 
    ON rm.rmap_no = e.rmap_no
    AND s.zone_no = e.zone_no
```

However when I run the SP I get this error:

> Msg 317, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_SALES, Line 119
>   Table-valued function 'FT_GET_PRICES' cannot have a column alias.

I figured SQL wanted me to do something like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES(getdate())  (NOLOCK) 
    ON rm.rmap_no = [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES.rmap_no
    AND s.zone_no = [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES.zone_no
```

...but I still get the error saying I'm using an alias. How do I fix this and how can I refer to the function in the stored procedure without an alias?

Comment: what do you get from `select * from FT_GET_PRICES(getdate())` ?

Comment: Why are you using NOLOCK when dealing with prices? Are you ok with the prices being inaccurate? My guess is you need to use APPLY here but with such a small portion it is hard to see what is going on. If you are going to use NOLOCK you need to also use the WITH keyword. Excluding that keyword is deprecated for table hints and will be required. Here is some detailed info about NOLOCK. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: + not sure you need that nolock

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is because you left off the WITH keyword and the engine thinks you are trying to alias the column as NOLOCK and you can't alias a column in a table valued function. To solve the issue either add WITH or better, remove NOLOCK.

Comment: @AaronBertrand are you sure? Since they left off WITH won't it try to alias the column(s) from the table valued function?

Comment: @Sean maybe, if it's a modern version (of course there is no version info in the question). Obviously dropping NOLOCK is one solution, and see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71176/1186 for more info...

Comment: @Sean (To be clear, with or without WITH, you will get an error, it's just a matter of which error you get. The locking hints should be placed inside the function, if that's actually desired state anyway, which I'm guessing it probably isn't, this is just another knee-jerk "go faster!" hint.)

Comment: To apply the NOLOCK hint to everything, put this at the top of your SP: `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`. Now you don't need all those `(NOLOCK)` sprinkled throughout.  But you should understand that NOLOCK / Read uncommitted is not a magic go fast switch.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the link. I have never even considered using NOLOCK on a tvf. Makes sense that you can't use hints though, just never considered it.

Comment: Thanks, it was the (NOLOCK). I'm renovating an old SP due to a program upgrade. Had to replace a now-defunct table (in part) with that function. It didn't register that I no longer needed the NOLOCK from the original.

Answer (score 2):

It's treating (nolock) as a column alias for the function. Remove it and try.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES(getdate()) e
```

ON rm.rmap_no = e.rmap_no
and s.zone_no = e.zone_no

Comment: You have to have an alias for the function here which you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `CROSS APPLY` like

```
CROSS APPLY [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES(getdate())(rm.rmap_no, s.zone_no)
```

Or probably use a derived query like

```
select .... from some_table rm
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
select * from [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES(getdate())
) e ON rm.rmap_no = e.rmap_no
```

Comment: This still doesn't address how to have `WITH (NOLOCK)` against the TVF ([actual answer is here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71176/1186)).

Answer (score 1):

Locking hints on TVFunctions like this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES(getdate())  (NOLOCK)
```

will generate that alias error. If you need to use such hints (which you don't in this case), put them in a select query expression and not part of the join syntax directly. So,

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].FT_GET_PRICES(getdate())
```

will fix the alias error.